# Calculating log returns over columns of a data frame + store the results in a new data frame

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, simplify

My data frame contains 22 columns: "DATE", "INDEX" and S1, S2, S3 ... S20. There are over 4322 rows. I want to calculate log returns and store the results in a data frame. That should give me 4321 rows.

I run this code, but I am sure there is a much more elegant way to do the calculation in a short way.

```
# count the sum of rows in order to make the following formula work appropriately - (n-1)
n <- nrow(df)

# calculating the log returns (natural logarithm), of INDEX and S1-20
LogRet_INDEX <- log(df$INDEX[2:n])-log(df$INDEX[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S1 <- log(df$S1[2:n])-log(df$S1[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S2 <- log(df$S2[2:n])-log(df$S2[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S3 <- log(df$S3[2:n])-log(df$S3[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S4 <- log(df$S4[2:n])-log(df$S4[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S5 <- log(df$S5[2:n])-log(df$S5[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S6 <- log(df$S6[2:n])-log(df$S6[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S7 <- log(df$S7[2:n])-log(df$S7[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S8 <- log(df$S8[2:n])-log(df$S7[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S9 <- log(df$S9[2:n])-log(df$S8[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S10 <- log(df$S10[2:n])-log(df$S10[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S11 <- log(df$S11[2:n])-log(df$S11[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S12 <- log(df$S12[2:n])-log(df$S12[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S13 <- log(df$S13[2:n])-log(df$S13[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S14 <- log(df$S14[2:n])-log(df$S14[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S15 <- log(df$S15[2:n])-log(df$S15[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S16 <- log(df$S16[2:n])-log(df$S16[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S17 <- log(df$S17[2:n])-log(df$S17[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S18 <- log(df$S18[2:n])-log(df$S18[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S19 <- log(df$S19[2:n])-log(df$S19[1:(n-1)])
LogRet_S20 <- log(df$S20[2:n])-log(df$S20[1:(n-1)])

# adding the results from the previous calculation (log returns) to a data frame
LogRet_df <- data.frame(LogRet_INDEX, LogRet_S1, LogRet_S2, LogRet_S3, LogRet_S4, LogRet_S5, LogRet_S6, LogRet_S7, LogRet_S8, LogRet_S9, LogRet_S10, LogRet_S11, LogRet_S12, LogRet_S13, LogRet_S14, LogRet_S15, LogRet_S16, LogRet_S17, LogRet_S18, LogRet_S19, LogRet_S20)
```

Is there a possibility to make this code shorter? Maybe some kind of loop or using a for argument? Since I am quite new to R, I try to improve my knowledge.

Any kind of help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `sapply` to apply a function to each column of the data.frame.

What the code below does, is 1) take columns 2 to 22 from the data frame called `df`. 2) for each of this columns, calculate logarithm of the respective column and then calculate the difference between two neighboring rows. 3) when done, convert it to `data.frame` called `df2`

```
df2 <- as.data.frame(sapply(df[2:22], function(x) diff(log(x))))
```